# Combobox autogenerating items

Tags: c#, wpf

I have Observable collection that is shared and bound between multiple WPF combo boxes and data grid.

For some reason the combo boxes generate items very slowly and hogging UI thread, and the strange thing is that they start generating items even if you dont try to access them (opening drop down menu).

It seem that it doesn't have to do with any data template or container styles as if i create a new observable collection with the same items then item generation is fast.

Could this be somehow related to CollectionView?
The data grid has its own collection view for the items collection and combo boxes are directly bound to ObservableCollection itself.

Comment: Include the shortest code possible to replicate the issue, otherwise we will just be speculating at what you might have done to cause the problem

Comment: @NullReference : Go to google.com and type **async await c#**

Comment: @IDisposable Indeed i use async await to populate the collection and indeed it seems that if collection is populated on UI thread the behavior vanishes. The question is how this can be fixed ?
I use BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization to enable the cross thread manipulation on the items collection and that should be enough as i understand. So how this could affect the normal operation?

Comment: I think i found the problem.
I had BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization called with different lock object called on same collection, just one call with single lock seem to fixed it.

Comment: From all the data you have shared, I still think that there is some long running operation that is blocking the UI thread. Maybe async and await is not done properly or some other operation on UI is causing that behavior.  If you want more help you need to show us your code. without that, all we could do is just guess. :)

Comment: You probably right and i am looking into it. I think its my ICommand to async execution code.

Comment: Yea. I guess some dead lock scenario? 
Good that you found out the solution.

Comment: It seem that the problem still persist and i am starting to bang my head against the wall.
It doesn't seem to be a dead lock as during slow generation there is no freezing of UI just bad responsiveness and high CPU usage.

I have created a test project with similar code and it works as it should even with much larger collections so i am stuck :(

Comment: It seem that all the delay happens here ProcessCrossThreadRequests()

Comment: OK after hours of searching i found that this is caused by setting SelectedValuePath on any items control that bound to the items collection.
It doesn't matter if items collection is bound to one or multiple itemscontrols neither it matters if source collection is populated on UI thread or not.

So this should be reformulated to can we have a better performance with SelectedValuePath set ?